# Mock a Lambda Layer in AWS Lambda Function

Tags: python, aws-lambda, mocking, python-unittest, aws-lambda-layers

I want to unit test my AWS Lambda Function. The problem is, the Lambda Functions rely on Lambda Layers, which are called in AWS Lambda environment

```
import os
import function from lambda_layer #this is called fine in AWS Lambda, but not locally

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    result = function(param1, param2)
    print(result)
    ....
```

In the unit test:

```
from unittest import TestCase
from unittest import mock


#this is where I need help:
with mock.patch(...... replace the lambda_layer with some mocked value or path to lambda layer???
    from path.to.lambda import lambda_hander as under_test

class TestStuff(TestCase):
    def test_lambda_handler(self):
        #given, when then....
```

Error message: E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lambda_layer'
.... obviously. But how can I fix this?

Comment: I assume you mean `from lambda_layer import function`?

Answer (score 2):

Lambda layers are essentially modules, which can be mocked just like any other.

However it is slightly more difficult if you need to completely replace a module that does not exist on your system, you need to set up a mock in [`sys.modules`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.modules) and then you can import the inexistent module.

`lambda_function.py`

```py
from inexistent import bar, foo


def lambda_hander():
    return foo() + bar()
```

`test_lambda_function.py`

```py
import sys
import unittest
from unittest.mock import MagicMock, patch

mock_inexistent = MagicMock()
sys.modules["inexistent"] = mock_inexistent  # test wide patching

import lambda_function  # noqa: E402 avoid complaint if using flake8


class TestInexistentModule(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_lambda_handler(self):

        mock_inexistent.foo.return_value = "foo"
        mock_inexistent.bar.return_value = "bar"

        self.assertEqual(lambda_function.lambda_hander(), "foobar")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

**NB.** this can also be achieved via [`unittest.mock.patch.dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch-dict), which actually shows it as one of its examples.

Runs just as expected.

```
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.003s

OK
```